# RSS Feed Stocks

Tags: rss, feed, stocks

I didn't realize until today that you can't get an RSS feed for a stock quote.  Can someone suggest to me ways I can pull data from a service for a particular stock quote?  It should include information about the stock etc.  Thanks.  I will be working in .NET.

Comment: Have you tried googling?

Comment: RSS is designed for discrete data.  What resolution would you want such a feed, with continuously fluctuating prices, to have?  More generally, what are you going to do with this data?  That will help people answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo! provides a CSV extract of stock data.

http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm